# Creating 'ReverseProxy' for Crystal Reports web API in .Net Core 6.0

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reverse-proxy, .net-4.8, asp.net-core-6.0

We have Crystal Reports on a old Web API, we are moving to .Net Core 6 wherever we can, i understand that Crystal Reports is not compatible with .Net Core and no immediate possibility of Crystal Reports being updated to do so.

I understand this, however in my research I found some users were able to create a ReverseProxy in a Seperate project that holds the Crystal Reports on a .Net 4.8 framework and the WebAPI being on .Net core 6. I however have not found any examples of doing so and how to accomplish this, and I personally have never created a proxy so not sure how to go about this and getting this to work for us(maybe). Does anyone have any examples of setting up a reverse proxy for crystal reports? or something that could help point me in the right direction to creating my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below blog, it will inspire you.

[Crystal Report to PDF Viewing with Angular and Asp.Net WebAPI](https://medium.com/scrum-and-coke/view-crystal-report-in-pdf-with-angular-and-asp-net-rest-api-1d6c72168e7c)

If you want use reverse proxy, please [setup IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy for real world apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222).